# Check for which package the Broadcast Receiver was intended

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, package

I want to send the INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast to my application for code referrals but I get a null pointer exception when I try to retrieve the package name which was broadcast:

```
intent.getPackage();  // returns null
```

This is the code that I am using.

In BroadcastReceiver class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null)
        return;
    String pack = context.getPackageName().toString();
    String intentpack = intent.getPackage();
    intentpack = intent.getDataString();
    if (intentpack.equals(pack))
```

I have added the intent-filter in the manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I am sending the broadcast from **ADB SHELL**

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n <package.name>/.MyReceiver --es "key" "multiple values here"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code from

```
intent.getPackage()
```

to

```
intent.getComponent().getPackageName();
```

and it worked!